# Wordpress Admin Save button doesn't work on custom template

Tags: wordpress, admin, php-8

I have a strange thing with a custom template (not mine) in Wordpress admin. When I open the customizer and change some input, the save button stays greyed out. It's apparently a problem with PHP 8.x as it works flawlessly in 7.x
What I wonder is why, I would have expected it's some JS, but as soon as I change the php version it works.
Anyone a wild guess?

Update: It only works if I downgrade to Wordpress 5.x which runs with PHP 7.4.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Check PHP error logs to see what the issue is in PHP 8.

Comment: nothing there, that's the "funny" thing, not even WP Debug showing anything